# Is there an "instanceof" functionality in the template engine of the Play framework?

Tags: java, inheritance, playframework-2.0, instanceof

I would like to know if there is some kind of `instanceof` functionality in the template engine of the Play (2.0) framework. This would allow me to effectively use the inheritance structure in my model layer.

This is basically what I would like (except that this template doesn't compile):

```
@(instance: Superclass)

@main { 
    @if(instance instanceof Subclass) {
        Subclass instanceOfSubclass = (Subclass) instance;    
    }
}
```

**Edit:** I mean in specific Play for Java.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use Scala pattern matching.

```
@(instance: Superclass)

@main { 
  @instance match {
    case foo: Foo => {
      <a href="@routes.Foo.index()">@foo.title</a>
    }
    case bar: Bar => {
      <a href="@routes.Bar.index()">@bar.title</a>
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It's weird to me that it works in the java world, because `Foo` and `Bar` must have extractor (unapply) for pattern matching. I'm currious now to know that does the trick. Any clue?

Comment: I don't know for sure. On the one hand, this pattern match only checks for the type. On the other hand, Play still does some bytecode magic in Java. Otherwise the Scala templates wouldn't make much sense in a framework that offers an API for both Java and Scala.

Comment: Indeed... I must be tired... The listi.G definitivelly foes not need